# tuple() in python is splitting strings when it shouldn't

Tags: python, split, list-comprehension

I'm trying to convert a list of strings into a list of tuples of those strings.
When I use tuple() in python it splits each string into its constituents.

```
print(BPID_list)
BPID_list = [tuple(x) for x in BPID_list]
print(BPID_list)

>['900383', '7716922', '99140154']
>[('9', '0', '0', '3', '8', '3'), ('7', '7', '1', '6', '9', '2', '2'), ('9', '9', '1', '4', '0', '1', '5', '4')]
```

but when I use the following code

```
for x in BPID_list:
    print(x)
>900383
>7716922
>99140154
```

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: Yes, this is what should happen. Were you looking for a different outcome?

Comment: I'm looking for each one to remain the way it was in the original list without being split

Comment: If you want to have a tuple with just the string, you need to do `tuple(x,)`, otherwise tuple iterates over individual characters of the string.

Comment: So why bother with the transformation if you want the original list?

Comment: If you simply want each string to be contained in a tuple, you need to remove the call to `tuple` and use `(x, )`

Comment: You mean `[(x,) for x in BPID_list]`?

Comment: Because i need a list of tuples to feed it through cur.executemany()

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
BPID_list = [(x,) for x in BPID_list]
```

In your example, it should provide the following:

```
[('900383',), ('7716922',), ('99140154',)]
```